# How to implement a trait in Rust which modifies a field of self?

Tags: rust, traits, self

So how to do this:

```
pub trait Thing {
    fn do_stuff(&mut self) {
        self.some_field = true;
    }
}
```

This won't compile because `self.some_field` is not defined. But the users of this trait would have that field. This would work without a default implementation, but the whole point of the trait is to provide default implementations for certain methods and share functionality that way.

```
struct Foo {
    some_field: bool
}

// I want this to have a `do_stuff()` method by default.
impl Thing for Foo {}
```

EDIT: so just to make it clear, is the linked answer the "best practice" solution for the problem?

I mean, having a bunch os similar structs requiring common functionality to be shared among them is a pretty common need. In other languages you would create a common ancestor and make the subclasses inherit these methods. But there is no inheritance in Rust.
So is implementing this using a macro (as described in the linked answer) the best solution for this?

Comment: By design, what you're trying to do is impossible in Rust. Traits are specifically designed to not require types to contain any specific fields. What is the specific problem you're trying to solve which makes you want to reach for this as a solution?

I think you're question is a good one, but recommend adding details for the problem you're trying to solve so people can supply answers concerning idiomatic Rust solutions to the problem.

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes, but I was hoping for a simpler solution :) Anyway thanks, i will  look into this answer.

Comment: traits can not use fields, and can only use their own or their super traits’ methods. So the way to do this would be for the trait to have an abstract method exposing either setting the field or getting a mutable reference. And maybe a declarative macro to implement it. At which point the trait becomes questionable, the macro alone might do the job if you don’t need to abstract (no generics or sun) but just want convenience.

Comment: @effect What I'm trying to do is sharing common methods between similar "objects". I have Reml4 components which render forms and they all need validation functions. I want to create a trait to share the validation functionality.